# Get Transaction by Hash

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc, transactions

I'd like to get transaction info like sender and receiver address etc. by sending transaction hash as a parameter.

I did found "api.rpc.eth.getTransactionByHash" and tried to pass the hash but it was giving me `"TypeError: api.rpc.eth.getTransactionByHash is not a function"` error.

Here is my code:

```
const dotAddress = async () => {
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider("wss://rpc.polkadot.io");
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  const result = api.rpc.eth.getTransactionByHash(
    "0x334cdf788cd4449139ce7dc83bf448b5ef2addb88bf6b642ac43880137e75387"
  );
  console.log(result);
};
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The API will decorate the endpoints based on what is available on the node, e.g. `rpc_methods` and in the runtime metadata. Polkadot is not an ETH-compatible chain, it doesn't have the Frontier pallet. The `eth.*` namespace will only be available on chains with Frontier.

Comment: So... Is there any endpoints on polkadot chain which returns me transaction summary? I digged into documentation but couldn't find anything related. By the way thank you for your explanation Jaco!

Comment: In Substrate, transaction hashes are not unique, there is no RPC to retrieve by tx hash. Here is a link to the [Polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#unique-identifiers-for-extrinsics) that explains the non-uniqueness of transaction hashes.

Answer (score 2):

The node itself doesn't index all transactions, it just stores blocks and states. You should fetch all blocks yourself and index transactions if you want to look them up that way.

Also note that transaction hash is [not a unique identifier](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#unique-identifiers-for-extrinsics) for a state transition (although is a unique identifier for a specific set of instructions and account context).

Comment: How can I index transactions from block? I tried ```api.query.transactionStorage.transactions(blockNumber)```, I am getting error. It seems transactionStorage is undefined

Comment: If it is undefined, it means it is not exposed in the runtime, i.e. there is no pallet for this. The [getBlock RPC](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getblockhash-blockhash-signedblock) returns the full block, based on hash (with the extrinsics included)