# Unable to retrieve header and parent from supplied hash

Tags: extrinsic

I am trying to execute a simple extrinsic but for some reason, it gives the error `Unable to retrieve header and parent from supplied hash`.

I don't think my problem has anything to with the extrinsic, but here is an example of extrinsic which I was executing. My end goal is to call this extrinsic through polkadot.js API, but since it was failing I tried to test it through Polkadot UI.

```
fn update_resource(resource:[u8; 32]){
  ....
}
```

I would like to understand what exactly the above error msg means.

Any feedback or help is most appreciated. Thank you..!

Comment: Please include a bit more context. What tool were you using to construct the extrinsic?

Comment: I am using Polkadot UI to test the extrinsic. @Bruno

Comment: If you can create something reproducible that I can test that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apps UI only retrieves block hashes, not extrinsic hashes. So when the error above occurs, it would mean you passed an invalid block hash which is not found [via RPC](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getblockhash-blockhash-signedblock).

Since there is no [lookup-by-tx-hash RPC](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/get-transaction-by-hash), the UI mentioned cannot lookup by that.

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm, instead of clearing the cache I ran the node in incognito mode which gets rid of this error as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error in the Polkadot UI/dashboard while submitting an extrinsic: "`Unable to retrieve header and parent from supplied hash.`" under the following conditions:

- even a simple balance transfer fails in the same way
- local chain development
- you restarted your chain

Then try clearing your browser cache.

I also got this error when trying an extrinsic through the dashboard when connected to a local chain. I attempted a simple balance transfer and this failed with the above error. This issue crops up for me fairly often when I'm developing, if I've restarted my chain, even after deleting the chain db.  Clearing the browser cache fixes it.

Yep, browser clinging to its cache for dear life strikes again.